# Sending out IMs to Lync/OCS programmatically

Tags: java, python, sip, lync, office-communicator

I need to send out Instant Messages to a Lync/OCS server from Linux programmatically as an alerting mechanism.

I've looked into using python dbus and pidgin-sipe with finch or pidgin, but they aren't really good for sending one-off instant messages  (finch and pidgin need to be running all the time).

Ideally, I'd have a python script or java class that could spit out Instant Messages to users when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are on Lync 2013, you can have a look at UCWA ucwa.lync.com. It's a web service that allows to log in to Lync and use IM, presence, etc.
You can use then any language you want. I played with it using Node on Mac OS X, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but, i've an experimental java api which can communicate with Lync 2013 UCWA. [Here is the github page](https://github.com/mtorak/java-lync-client)

You are welcome to fork it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this service.
Would you mind posting some code that explain how to use it?

Comment: You'r welcome @user2360915, you can check out the issues section, there is an ongoing QA there.